# How to Compile/Deploy A Python Application With Python-VLC Module

Tags: python, vlc, buildozer, kivymd, recipe

1. **python-vlc==3.0.12117**
2. **python =3.9.0**
3. **kivymd = 0.104.2.dev0**

I have made a program using `pafy` and `python-vlc` using `KivyMD`. The issue is that when I want to deploy my application using `buildozer` it gives the following error :

```
AttributeError: undefined symbol: PyFile_FromFd
```

This is caused by something inside the `vlc.py` that is created when buildozer imports it from the ***buildozer.spec*** which I specified in the requirements :

```
requirements = python3,kivy,pafy==0.5.1,youtube-dl==2021.4.7,python-vlc==3.0.12117
```

### Log After Running The Command :

`buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/daniel/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 5a94d074 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2244 from Chronolife-team/native_services_upstream
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK found at /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
# Check application requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,pafy==0.5.1,youtube-dl==2021.4.7,python-vlc==3.0.12117 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py'
# Cwd /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
# Build the application #6
# Copy application source from /home/daniel/Projects/pafy
# Create directory /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/main.py
# Copy /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/log
# Copy /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/yt_mod_1.py
# Copy /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/demo.kv
# Copy /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/LICENSE
# Package the application
# project.properties updated
# Gradle project detected, copy files /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/src/main/java
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name \'My Application\' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py'
# Cwd /home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Listing '/tmp/p4a-extra-env-_n6dk4jp'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'...
Compiling '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...
Compiling '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
Compiling '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app/yt_mod_1.py'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/modules'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/Kivy-1.11.1-py3.8.egg-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/android'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/bin'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/certifi'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/certifi-2021.5.30.dist-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/etc'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/etc/bash_completion.d'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/etc/fish'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/etc/fish/completions'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src/org'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src/org/jnius'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/audio'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/camera'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/gl'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/image'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/spelling'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/text'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/video'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/window'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/fonts'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/glsl'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/images'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/keyboards'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/deps'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/effects'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/extras'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/garden'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/cgl_backend'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/include'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input/postproc'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input/providers'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lang'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/modules'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/network'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/storage'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/gles_compat'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/highlight'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/packaging'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/pep8checker'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/theming'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix/recycleview'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pafy'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pafy-0.5.1.dist-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pkg_resources'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/pyjnius-1.2.1-py3.8.egg-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/python_vlc-3.0.12117.dist-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools/command'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools/extern'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/setuptools-40.9.0-py3.8.egg-info'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/share'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/share/doc'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/share/doc/youtube_dl'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/share/man'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/share/man/man1'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local/bin'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/youtube_dl'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/youtube_dl/postprocessor'...
Listing '/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/youtube_dl-2021.4.7.dist-info'...
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Android packaging done!
# APK myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory
# Run '/home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
List of devices attached
ZF6222XFZM  device

# Deploy on ZF6222XFZM
# Run '/home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r "/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/bin/myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"'
# Cwd /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform
Performing Streamed Install
Success
# Application pushed.
# Run on ZF6222XFZM
# Run '/home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity -a org.kivy.android.PythonActivity'
# Cwd /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform
Starting: Intent { act=org.kivy.android.PythonActivity cmp=org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity }
# Waiting for application to start.
# Application started.
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/daniel/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Run '/home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat *:S python:D '
# Cwd /home/daniel/.buildozer/android/platform
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : calculated paths to be...
06-17 12:41:26.121 22920 23063 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
06-17 12:41:26.122 22920 23063 I python  : set wchar paths...
06-17 12:41:26.245 22920 23063 I python  : Initialized python
06-17 12:41:26.245 22920 23063 I python  : AND: Init threads
06-17 12:41:26.247 22920 23063 I python  : testing python print redirection
06-17 12:41:26.249 22920 23063 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
06-17 12:41:26.249 22920 23063 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/oem-services.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/legacy-test.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '9', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
06-17 12:41:26.249 22920 23063 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
06-17 12:41:26.249 22920 23063 I python  : AND: Ran string
06-17 12:41:26.249 22920 23063 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
06-17 12:41:26.518 22920 23063 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
06-17 12:41:26.518 22920 23063 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
06-17 12:41:26.531 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-06-17_0.txt
06-17 12:41:26.532 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
06-17 12:41:26.532 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
06-17 12:41:26.533 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Jun 16 2021, 11:10:28) 
06-17 12:41:26.533 22920 23063 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
06-17 12:41:26.533 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
06-17 12:41:28.287 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
06-17 12:41:28.382 22920 23063 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
06-17 12:41:30.713 22920 23063 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
06-17 12:41:30.714 22920 23063 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
06-17 12:41:30.715 22920 23063 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/vlc.py", line 386, in <module>
06-17 12:41:30.715 22920 23063 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 386, in __getattr__
06-17 12:41:30.716 22920 23063 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/Projects/pafy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 391, in __getitem__
06-17 12:41:30.717 22920 23063 I python  :  AttributeError: undefined symbol: PyFile_FromFd
06-17 12:41:30.717 22920 23063 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I was suggested by  someone on discord that I should build a custom recipe for python-vlc but I am unsure on how to do that (even after reading p4a and buildozer docs for it).GitHub repository

Here is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/1MochaChan1/pafy) with the project I want to compile

Comment: always post the full error logs, even when you're not sure

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've added the error log as well can you check and let me know if you understand the issue? I feel I need to make a kivy recipe for this but whenever I try to do it by looking at other references it mostly feels overwhelming because I am not familiar with what's going on.